# Using generator expression in `cmake -E copy` command

Tags: cmake

I am trying to copy dll files from my bin folder to a different folder. I want to copy files from bin/Debug when building in Debug and from bin/Release when building in Release. This is what I currently use (and which does not work).

```
file(GLOB library_files_debug ${outputdirectory_root}/Debug/*.dll)
file(GLOB library_files_release ${outputdirectory_root}/Release/*.dll)

add_custom_target(copy_dlls_to_wheel ALL
    DEPENDS setup.py
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Debug files: $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${library_files_debug}>"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Release files: $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${library_files_release}>"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Destination dir: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME}"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${library_files_debug}> $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${library_files_release}> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME}

    )
```

I am running on Windows 10, and use Visual Studio to build. When the above target `copy_dlls_to_wheel` is built in Debug, the first echo statement prints out the correct dll files, and the second echo is empty. However, no files are copied. Instead I get the error message `The system cannot find the path specified.`

I have also tried to replace the last line with

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${library_files_debug}> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME}
```

, but I get the same result.

However, when I remove the generator expression, and use

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${library_files_debug} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME}
```

the files are copied correctly to my output folder. I am pretty confident my generator expression is correct, since I get the expected output from the echo commands. Are generator expressions not supported when using `cmake -E copy`, or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake's command line [`copy`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) is able to process multiple files when you simply provide a *list*, which is why this works:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${library_files_debug} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME}
```

This is expanded to a **space-separated** list of files when the `copy` command is ultimately executed, which is the expected syntax.

```
cmake.exe -E copy mylib1.dll mylib2.dll /your/binary/dir/python/proj
```

However, when wrapped in a generator expression, the list will **not** be interpreted correctly by CMake. While the generator expression will be evaluated correctly, the list will be kept as a **semicolon-separated** list of files, which is the incorrect syntax:

```
cmake.exe -E copy "mylib1.dll;mylib2.dll" /your/binary/dir/python/proj
```

This causes the `copy` command to fail.

To work-around this issue, you could loop over each DLL file you want to copy, if there aren't too many. Something like this could work:

```
# Loop through the Debug files.
foreach(cur_file ${library_files_debug})
    get_filename_component(file_name ${cur_file} NAME)
    add_custom_target(copy_dlls_to_wheel_debug_${file_name} ALL
        DEPENDS setup.py
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "DLL file: ${cur_file}"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Destination dir: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${cur_file}> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME}
        )
endforeach()
# Loop through the Release files.
foreach(cur_file ${library_files_release})
    get_filename_component(file_name ${cur_file} NAME)
    add_custom_target(copy_dlls_to_wheel_release_${file_name} ALL
        DEPENDS setup.py
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "DLL file: ${cur_file}"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Destination dir: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${cur_file}> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME}
        )
endforeach()
```

A quicker solution might be to bundle up your DLLs, using CMake's `tar` command line utility, copy them, then extract them, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14369556/3987854) answer. CMake's `tar` command does not seem to accept lists wrapped in generator expressions either, so the list of files to bundle together is written to a file.

```
file(GLOB library_files_debug ${outputdirectory_root}/Debug/*.dll)
file(GLOB library_files_release ${outputdirectory_root}/Release/*.dll)

# Write the filenames (not full path) of the files to pack to file
set(debug_content "")
set(release_content "")

foreach(lib_file ${library_files_debug})
    get_filename_component(file_name ${lib_file} NAME)
    set(debug_content "${debug_content}${file_name}\n")
endforeach(lib_file ${library_files_debug})

foreach(lib_file ${library_files_release})
    get_filename_component(file_name ${lib_file} NAME)
    set(release_content "${release_content}${file_name}\n")
endforeach(lib_file ${library_files_release})

set(filenames_debug ${outputdirectory_root}/debug_files.txt)
set(filenames_release ${outputdirectory_root}/release_files.txt)
file(WRITE ${filenames_debug} ${debug_content})
file(WRITE ${filenames_release} ${release_content})

# Read either the list of debug or release files, and pack files
add_custom_command(
    TARGET bdist PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cfj" ${outputdirectory_root}/temp.tar --files-from="$<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,${filenames_debug},${filenames_release}>"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${outputdirectory_root}/$<CONFIG>)

# Unpack the files in the folder building the python wheel
add_custom_command(
    TARGET bdist PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rename ${outputdirectory_root}/temp.tar temp.tar
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "xfj" temp.tar
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove temp.tar
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful. I didn't konw that you couldn't pass semicolon-separated list to the copy command. I don't have too many files, so a loop should be allright. However, I don't quite understand your suggestion. As far as I understand, I need to use the generator expressions inside the custom target, to add either debug or release dll-files. Any suggestion on how I can do that?

Comment: @larsjr You typically *can* pass a list to the `copy` command, just not when it is wrapped in a generator expression. And apologies, the syntax in my initial answer was not quite right. My suggestion loops over each file, creating a *separate* custom target for each file. This is a bit ugly, and essentially removes the need for the generator expressions, which is why I also suggested checking out CMake's `tar` utility.

Comment: Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but wouldn't your suggestion copy _both_ the debug and release files? I need to only copy one set of files, depending on which build configuration is used. That's why I thought I needed to use a generator expression. I will check out CMake's `tar` utility, as you suggested.

Comment: @larsjr You are correct, for a configuration-dependent copy as you want, you would need two loop. I adjusted my answer to reflect this. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting the loop code to run. CMake gives an error saying that the copy command is used incorrectly. Perhaps a wrong number of arguments is given when the generator expressions returns false, since the file to copy then ends up being an empty string? I tried out your suggestion with CMake's `tar` which   turned out to work, so I have suggested an edit to your answer where I've added code the for this.

Comment: @larsjr Thanks for your additions, and I'm glad you found something that works!