# Is there anything like a forwarding C++ preprocessor, that could be used by GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, preprocessor

I've been searching around for different custom pre-processor extensions and replacements, but all of them seem to come with 1 of 2 caveats:

Either 1), you generate the code as a separate build-system, them manually put the output into your real (CMake) build system, or 2) you end up losing the builtin preprocessor for GCC.

Is there really no tool that can, say, run each file it gets against some configured script, then through cpp, then pass the result to gcc?

I'd love to use something like [Cog](https://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog) by just setting an environment variable for gcc, indicating a tool that runs Cog first and then the standard preprocessor.

Alternatively, is there a straightforward way to accomplish that in CMake, itself? I don't want to have to write a custom script for each file, especially if I have to then hard-code the compiler/preprocessor flags in each target.

edit: For clarity, I am aware of several partial/partially-applicable solutions. For example, how to tell GCC to use a different preprocessor. (Or really, to look in a different place for its own preprocessor, cc1. See: [Custom gcc preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545875/custom-gcc-preprocessor)) However, that leaves a lot of work to do, to modify files, and then correctly invoke the *real* cc1, with the correct original arguments.

Since that is effectively a constant/generic problem, I'm just surprised there is no drop in program.

Edit 2: After looking over several proposed solutions, I am not convinced there is an answer to this question. For example, if files are going to be generated by CMake, then they can't be included and browsed by the IDE - due to not yet existing.

As ridiculous as it sounds, I don't think there is any way to extend the preprocessor short of forking Gcc. Everything recommended so far, constitutes incomplete hacks.

Comment: Your question is not really clear, but there are plenty of code generation tools out there (e.g. that interpret some input file or script, and output C code).   For example, Bison takes an input description of a grammar, and outputs code that can parse an input file consistently with that grammar - it is used to generate parsers for GNU compilers.

Comment: Is there a preprocessor that will subsequently invoke another (for example, the builtin one), automatically, and will function when invoked by GCC? (Gcc can be told where to find its preprocessor with a flag.)

Comment: I'm not aware of any option to get gcc (or any other C or C++ compiler) to use a different preprocessor. There are plenty of options to control behaviour of the preprocessor, but (functionally, as well as implementation-wise) the preprocessor is a tightly coupled component - it and other components of the compiler suite are each designed with detailed knowledge of implementation details of the other.   That's one reason people use code generators - instead of trying to coerce a compiler to preprocess code in a non-standard way, use a program that outputs code for input to the compiler

Comment: Getting GCC to invoke another pre-processor is not the difficult part. It's forwarding the invocations between them. As you can see, this example drops the incoming configuration, and thus interrupts the build system. Meanwhile, GCC's builtin CPP, handles (re-)invoking GCC correctly. Which is great! I want that. I just want custom, as well. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545875/custom-gcc-preprocessor#)

Comment: sooo just https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545875/custom-gcc-preprocessor# and run two programs in the cc script?? `is there a straightforward way to accomplish that in CMake, itself? I don't want to have to write a custom script for each file` I do not understand. Write a script for all files. There is no "straightforward way", there is a normal way to generate sources with `add_custom_command`. Note, that you did not tag CMake. `that leaves a lot of work to do, to modify files` I do not understand that. What it "leaves to do", in what way exactly?

Comment: @KamilCuk Maybe I'm reading too much into snags I've hit along the way trying different things, but: 1) I don't think that example actually compiles, I think it's dumping preprocessor output, so there's the question of knowing which compiler to call, 2) I don't think the real cc1 is seeing any "modifications" by the additional processor, 3) I'm not sure how to integrate this into a real project where modified files have to be included in other files, etc. Or where files needing modification may be brought in by other files. Don't know how I missed the CMake tag! TY!

Comment: @KamilCuk I am reading through the repos you linked. I am not sure I understand exactly what these projects do, but it looks interesting.

Comment: People have generated C sources with M4 for decades using Makefiles, and it was pretty much a standard to use Autoconf. And your post asks "Is there really no tool that can" - this is not a programming question.

Comment: What do you need this for? C/C++ preprocessor is surprisingly powerful (check out Boost.Preprocessor), and can be shoehorned into doing loops/conditionals/...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Since I don't currently have a real solution, I: removed some features I can't effectively maintain, deprecated some of the projects I support, and replaced a few simple scripts (in C++ 20 projects) with with the new short Recursive Macro trick. BoostPP looks cool, but I've never been able to figure it out.
In one case, I just wanted to auto-generate fields and add their ptrs to an array. I couldn't figure out how to do this in BoostPP, so I just used the recursive macro trick.

Comment: @user41010 What's the recursive macro trick? I think I know, but I'm unsure.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/va-opt.html

Comment: I see. FYI, [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dY5co17qn) is how you do loops without the length limit and without much boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

The GCC (C++ compiler) is made for compiling C++ programs. As the C++ preprocessor is standardized within the C++ standard there is usually no need for anything like a "plugin" or "extension" there.

Don't listen to the comments, that suggest you using any exotic extension to CMake or change source code of GCC. Running source files through a different program (cog in your case) before compiling is a well known task and all major build systems support it right away.

In CMake you can use the [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#examples-generating-files) function. If you need this for more than one file, you could use a CMake loop like e.g. suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16998311/17862371).

Comment: CMak'e for-loop syntax does make this approach more palatable than at first glance. I have done this before with external scripts, and one of the problems I encountered was with error messages referring to transient files instead of the real ones. Among other issue. I guess I could look more into how people setup their cmake files for this purpose.